# How to setup CMake to build code which contains path-includes like #include <libdir/lib>?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile, cmake

I am trying to migrate an old C/C++ sunstudio project to visual studio 2019. I need to build targets on a remote linux machine, so I cannot use the visual studio solution to build. After some unsuccessful attempts to use the old sunstudio makefiles, I have decided to use **cmake** to build the project.

The problem is that the code references includes with relative paths, like this:

```
(tkamain.cxx):
#include <ukernel/inc/U.h>
#include <monitor/inc/monitor.h>
```

I don't want to touch the code, so how can I setup CMake to build this project properly with these specific include statements?

The project structure looks like this.

```
tka
|-mod
||-monitor
||'-inc
||-feedutils
||'-inc
|'-ukernel
| '-inc
|-inc
||-foo.hxx
|'-bar.hxx
|-src
||-foo.cxx
||-bar.cxx
||-tkamain.cxx
|'-CMakeLists.txt (CMakeB)
'-CMakeLists.txt (CMakeA)
```

The CMakeLists.txt are newly created by me and are probably not correctly set up yet.

The CMakeA file contains this:

```
project(tka)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

The CMakeB file contains this:

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/mod)
add_executable(tkamain tkamain.cxx)
```

The commands in CMakeB seem not to be sufficient for my purposes, what am I missing? Or do I need more CMakeLists.txt files?

The errors I am getting look like this:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/tkamain.dir/tkamain.cxx.o
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:11:27: error: ukernel/inc/U.h: No such file or directory
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:14:33: error: monitor/inc/monitor.h: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to give more specific include paths, like this, but that didn't help either:

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/mod/ukernel/inc)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/mod/monitor/inc)
```

When I run make VERBOSE=1, I get the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake -S/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src -B/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/out/build/Linux-Debug-test --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/out/build/Linux-Debug-test/CMakeFiles /drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/out/build/Linux-Debug-test/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/out/build/Linux-Debug-test'
make -f src/CMakeFiles/tkamain.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/tkamain.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/out/build/Linux-Debug-test'
cd /drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/out/build/Linux-Debug-test && /usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src /drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src /drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/out/build/Linux-Debug-test /drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/out/build/Linux-Debug-test/src /drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/out/build/Linux-Debug-test/src/CMakeFiles/tkamain.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/out/build/Linux-Debug-test'
make -f src/CMakeFiles/tkamain.dir/build.make src/CMakeFiles/tkamain.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory `/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/out/build/Linux-Debug-test'
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/tkamain.dir/tkamain.cxx.o
cd /drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/out/build/Linux-Debug-test/src && /usr/bin/c++   -I/inc  -g   -o CMakeFiles/tkamain.dir/tkamain.cxx.o -c /drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:11:27: error: ukernel/inc/U.h: No such file or directory
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:12:30: error: ukernel/inc/Ulib.h: No such file or directory
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:13:31: error: ukernel/inc/UExit.h: No such file or directory
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:14:33: error: monitor/inc/monitor.h: No such file or directory
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:31:26: error: tkacontrol.hxx: No such file or directory
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:24: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'U_OS'
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:37: error: 'UkInit' was not declared in this scope
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:39: error: 'TkaControl' was not declared in this scope
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:39: error: 'tkaControl' was not declared in this scope
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:39: error: expected type-specifier before 'TkaControl'
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:39: error: expected ';' before 'TkaControl'
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:41: error: 'UExitHandler' was not declared in this scope
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:41: error: expected ';' before 'exithandler'
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:43: error: 'Monitor2Startup' was not declared in this scope
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:45: error: 'evalarg_error' was not declared in this scope
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:46: error: 'UEXIT_STOP' was not declared in this scope
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:46: error: 'UExitMsg' was not declared in this scope
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:49: error: 'UkMain' was not declared in this scope
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:50: error: 'Monitor2Exit' was not declared in this scope
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:59: error: 'UEXIT_STOP' was not declared in this scope
/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/src/src/tkamain.cxx:59: error: 'UExitMsg' was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/tkamain.dir/tkamain.cxx.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/out/build/Linux-Debug-test'
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/tkamain.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/drive/new/home/mwe/.vs/tka/eb2f2a43-555a-3934-8996-0095b1bcc780/out/build/Linux-Debug-test'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Run a verbose build (`make VERBOSE=1`) and see the commands and *their options and flags* that are used when building. Make sure that the include-path options (`-I`, upper-case i) is correct.

Comment: @wegwerf: Have you tried TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(tkamain ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/mod) ?

Comment: @Gojita yes, both before the add_executable() and after. I did add PUBLIC as an option though.

Comment: @wegwerf: Ok but I do not see those file in the tree you sent. DO you have deleted them from the tree output ? I've you checked that the files are there ?

Comment: @wegwerf: This is not this output that he/she meant. But the output of a "make VERBOSE=1" (not a output of cmake)

Comment: @Gojita yes, sorry for the incomplete tree. The files that the errormessage mentions are where they should be.

Comment: The output of make VERBOSE=1 is in this pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/2T2pGghc

Comment: @wegwerf: Sorry, it's blocked by my proxy :-(. But you can look inside if you see the -I directive with the expected directories

Comment: @Gojita I have added it to the post. As you see, I am new to stackoverflow. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: @wegwerf: I only see "-I/inc" in your compilation line ... this means that your include_directories is not correct. By the way, try to not use include_directories. Stay with TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ... and give a try to TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(tkamin PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../mod) (and same with inc)

Comment: @Gojita will do, thanks. Do you think I am missing more directories because in my CMakeA I only include src? I added add_subdirectory(mod) too, but that doesn't help. Is that because I need a MakeLists.txt file in mod?

Comment: No. Normally, what you sent should work. I've run it locally on my computer and there's no problem with the -I directive

Comment: @wegworf: Which version of cmake do you use ?

Comment: @Gojita I have tried TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES, but nothing seems to have changed. I am using cmake version 3.15.2940156-MSVC_2, which is suggested by microsoft for remote building with visual studio.

Comment: @Gojita I haven't mentioned that mod contains symbolic links. Sorry if this turns out to be the issue. But I have checked and they point to correct locations. Specifically, the "inc"s in the subfolders of mod point to "/new/rel/monitor/inc". But the header files are there.

Comment: Please post (by editing your question post) the full paths to each of the symbolic links being used within the `mod` directory.

Answer (score 0):

With this:

```
# CMakeA
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(tka)
add_subdirectory(src)

# CMakeB
add_executable(tkamain tkamain.cxx)
target_include_directories(tkamain PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc)
target_include_directories(tkamain PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/mod)
```

When I run "cmake VERBOSE=1" I got the following output:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/tkamain.dir/tkamain.cxx.o
cd /home/lma/tmp/stackoverflow/tka/src && /usr/bin/c++   -I/home/lma/tmp/stackoverflow/tka/inc -I/home/lma/tmp/stackoverflow/tka/mod   -o CMakeFiles/tkamain.dir/tkamain.cxx.o -c /home/lma/tmp/stackoverflow/tka/src/tkamain.cxx
/home/lma/tmp/stackoverflow/tka/src/tkamain.cxx:1:10: fatal error: ukernel/inc/U.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ukernel/inc/U.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

As you can see, there's both directive
-I/home/lma/tmp/stackoverflow/tka/inc
-I/home/lma/tmp/stackoverflow/tka/mod

I propose you to start with the 2 little CMakeLists.txt I sent
And clean also all you cmake intermediate file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It looks like the problem was not with the CMake config, but with visual studio and the way the project is set up. I will edit the post to explain. But the issue seems to be resolved.